# Type extension for discriminated union in F#

Tags: f#, discriminated-union, type-extension

I have defined the following discriminated union:

```
type Expr = 
    | Con of Num
    | Var of Name
    | Add of Expr * Expr
    | Sub of Expr * Expr
    | Mult of Expr * Expr
    | Div of Expr * Expr
    | Pow of Expr * Expr
```

Then I created a pretty-printing function as follows:

```
let rec stringify expr =
    match expr with
    | Con(x) -> string x
    | Var(x) -> string x
    | Add(x, y) -> sprintf "(%s + %s)" (stringify x) (stringify y)
    | Sub(x, y) -> sprintf "(%s - %s)" (stringify x) (stringify y)
    | Mult(x, y) -> sprintf "(%s * %s)" (stringify x) (stringify y)
    | Div(x, y) -> sprintf "(%s / %s)" (stringify x) (stringify y)
    | Pow(x, y) -> sprintf "(%s ** %s)" (stringify x) (stringify y)
```

Now I want to make my `Expr` type use this function for its `ToString()` method. For example:

```
type Expr = 
    | Con of Num
    | Var of Name
    | Add of Expr * Expr
    | Sub of Expr * Expr
    | Mult of Expr * Expr
    | Div of Expr * Expr
    | Pow of Expr * Expr
    override this.ToString() = stringify this
```

But I can't do this, because `stringify` is not yet defined. The answer is to define `Stringify` as a member of `Expr`, but I don't want to pollute my initial type declaration with this specialized method that is going to keep growing over time. Therefore, I decided to use an abstract method that I could implement with an [intrinsic type extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233211.aspx) further down in the file. Here's what I did:

```
type Expr = 
    | Con of Num
    | Var of Name
    | Add of Expr * Expr
    | Sub of Expr * Expr
    | Mult of Expr * Expr
    | Div of Expr * Expr
    | Pow of Expr * Expr
    override this.ToString() = this.Stringify()
    abstract member Stringify : unit -> string
```

But I get the following compiler error:

> error FS0912: This declaration element is not permitted in an
>   augmentation

The message doesn't even seem correct (I'm not creating a type augmentation yet), but I understand why it's complaining. It doesn't want me to create an abstract member on a discriminated union type because it cannot be inherited. Even though I don't really want inheritance, I want it to behave like a partial class in C# where I can finish defining it somewhere else (in this case the same file).

I ended up "cheating" by using the late-binding power of the `StructuredFormatDisplay` attribute along with `sprintf`:

```
[<StructuredFormatDisplay("{DisplayValue}")>]
type Expr = 
    | Con of Num
    | Var of Name
    | Add of Expr * Expr
    | Sub of Expr * Expr
    | Mult of Expr * Expr
    | Div of Expr * Expr
    | Pow of Expr * Expr
    override this.ToString() = sprintf "%A" this

/* stringify function goes here */

type Expr with
    member public this.DisplayValue = stringify this
```

Although now `sprintf` and `ToString` both output the same string, and there is no way to get the `Add (Con 2,Con 3)` output as opposed to `(2 + 3)` if I want it.

So is there any other way to do what I'm trying to do?

P.S. I also noticed that if I place the `StructuredFormatDisplay` attribute on the augmentation instead of the original type, it doesn't work. This behavior doesn't seem correct to me. It seems that either the F# compiler should add the attribute to the type definition or disallow attributes on type augmentations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, `stringify` *must* grow along with the data type, otherwise it would end up with an incomplete pattern match. Any essential modification of the data type would require modifying the `stringify` as well. As a personal opinion, I would consider keeping both at the same place, unless the project is really complex.

However, since you prefer your DU type to be clear, consider wrapping the data type into a single-case DU:

```
// precede this with your definitions of Expr and stringify
type ExprWrapper = InnerExpr of Expr with
    static member Make (x: Expr) = InnerExpr x
    override this.ToString() = match this with | InnerExpr x -> stringify x

// usage
let x01 = Add(Con 5, Con 42) |> ExprWrapper.Make
printfn "%O" x01
// outputs: (5 + 42)
printfn "%s" (x01.ToString())
// outputs: (5 + 42)
printfn "%A" x01
// outputs: InnerExpr(Add (Con 5,Con 42))
```

Citation from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10152352/974789):

> In complex programs clear type signatures indeed make it easier to maintain composability.
>
> Not only it's simpler to add more cases to single-case DUs, but also it's easier to extend DUs with member and static methods.

Comment: I think I'll accept this even though I may not use it because it's at least a technique I didn't consider.

Answer (score 8):

Did you consider defining your `ToString` in the augmentation?

```
type Num = int
type Name = string

type Expr = 
    | Con of Num
    | Var of Name
    | Add of Expr * Expr
    | Sub of Expr * Expr
    | Mult of Expr * Expr
    | Div of Expr * Expr
    | Pow of Expr * Expr

let rec stringify expr =
    match expr with
    | Con(x) -> string x
    | Var(x) -> string x
    | Add(x, y) -> sprintf "(%s + %s)" (stringify x) (stringify y)
    | Sub(x, y) -> sprintf "(%s - %s)" (stringify x) (stringify y)
    | Mult(x, y) -> sprintf "(%s * %s)" (stringify x) (stringify y)
    | Div(x, y) -> sprintf "(%s / %s)" (stringify x) (stringify y)
    | Pow(x, y) -> sprintf "(%s ** %s)" (stringify x) (stringify y)

type Expr with
    override this.ToString() = stringify this
```

However, it *does* have the ugly side-effect of a

```
warning FS0060: Override implementations in augmentations are now deprecated. Override implementations should be given as part of the initial declaration of a type.
```

Comment: Yeah, that was what I actually started out with, but I think I thought that message was an error and not a warning. Still, your method may be the most-straightforward, even though it is "deprecated." I'm still curious if anyone else on here knows another way that is as simple but not deprecated.

Comment: Interestingly, this only works if I execute the entire script at once (by highlighting it in VS and pressing ALT-ENTER). IF I try to execute the type definition and augmentation separately, I get the `error FS0854: Method overrides and interface implementations are not permitted here` because the F# compiler can't override a method on an already-existing type. Maybe that dual behavior is the reason why they deprecated the behavior.

Comment: Well, a type *augmentation* ends up in the same class, when compiled. Whereas a type *extension* ends up as an extension method. The syntax is the same, however, so I kind of can understand that you have to execute it at the same time. (Not necessarily saying, it is very intuitive)

Comment: Ah, I'd forgot about that difference. MSDN seems to eschew the term *augmentation* and instead uses *intrinsic extension* versus *optional extension* to distinguish between them:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233211.aspx. And then the article slips up further down and says *implicit extension*. It still doesn't say what happens when you execute one in immediate mode (whether it is intrinsic or optional); but I suppose each block of code that you execute is treated like a separate "file," so that would make it *optional* I guess.

Comment: does this answer actually function, to the rest of .net (C#, etc..), as if it was defined on the type directly?

Comment: that is the idea, yes

Answer (score 6):

How about a solution that doesn't even require a type extension.

Instead, define a type with a static member which is stringify (we need the dummy type as `type a ... and b` requires `b` to be a type

```
type Num = string //missing
type Name = string //missing
type Expr = 
    | Con of Num
    | Var of Name
    | Add of Expr * Expr
    | Sub of Expr * Expr
    | Mult of Expr * Expr
    | Div of Expr * Expr
    | Pow of Expr * Expr
    override this.ToString() = type_dummy.stringify this
and type_dummy = 
    static member stringify expr =
        let stringify = type_dummy.stringify
        match expr with
        | Con(x) -> string x
        | Var(x) -> string x
        | Add(x, y) -> sprintf "(%s + %s)" (stringify x) (stringify y)
        | Sub(x, y) -> sprintf "(%s - %s)" (stringify x) (stringify y)
        | Mult(x, y) -> sprintf "(%s * %s)" (stringify x) (stringify y)
        | Div(x, y) -> sprintf "(%s / %s)" (stringify x) (stringify y)
        | Pow(x, y) -> sprintf "(%s ** %s)" (stringify x) (stringify y)
```

Comment: Yeah, but that requires that the two types be adjacent in the source file, which is what I was kind of trying to avoid. Still might be better than needing to put it directly on the type though.